# Loading multiple solutions into Visual Studio 2015 on start

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, devenv

I have multiple solutions generated by script from cMake and I want to open all at once in a Visual Studio instance.
I found /command as parameter of devenv.exe when running from command line.
There are commands like File.OpenProject and File.AddExistingProject, but I can only pass one of them to /command at the start.
As I see so far there is no character to separarate the commands in one string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That seems quite unlikely, surely you meant multiple *projects*?

Comment: No I have sln files

Comment: You would need to open each solution in its own instance of Studio

Comment: I can integrate existing solutions